# Arithmetic issue in a try block VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am relatively new to VB.NET and programming in general, so I am still learning the basics of syntax.

I keep getting an error that says

> End of statement expected

On the line `(b\0+1=1)`. How would I end this to solve the error? Thank you for any responses!

```
b = InputBox("Please Enter Radius.") 'enter radius
  Try (b\0+1 = 1)
     Exit Try
   Catch ex As NullReferenceException
     Console.WriteLine("Not a whole number. Please try again")
     Console.ReadLine()
      Exit Try
   End Try
```

Comment: Try/Catch defines a block - all the code should go inside it.  you cant specify a statement to try that way if thats what you are trying to do

Comment: You are dividing b by zero, you can't do that. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You also need to turn on Option Strict.  InputBox returns a string, you are (apparently) trying to do math on it.  I dont know what you are trying to do with `(b\0+1 = 1)` but its wrong.  You need to assign the result, but whatever test you are applying is wrong.  You dont really need a Try/Catch

Comment: a quick google search on "VB.net Try sample" reveals...samples!  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tbkaxz5(v=vs.100).aspx http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p4.html

Comment: `If q = Int(q) Then` should tell you if it is a whole number or not.  `q` would be the parsed value of the user input string

Comment: Try removing `Exit Try` and put `b = InputBox("Please Enter Radius.") 'enter radius` after the `Try`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"End of statement expected" means that you gave more on a line of code than it was expecting. In this case, it is because the `Try` must be on its own line.

For the problem of determining if the user has entered an integer, useful methods to convert text to integers are the [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. The former throws exceptions if something is wrong whereas the latter returns a Boolean indicating if the parse was successful.

A "NullReferenceException" is not what you want to catch: you should consult the documentation for the method which could throw an exception to see which exceptions it can throw. Sometimes it is sufficient to catch *any* exception:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim b As String
        Dim isGoodNumber As Boolean = True
        Dim radius As Integer

        ' OPTION ONE: Decline any bad input with a generic error message.
        Do
            b = InputBox("Please enter the radius as a whole number:")
            Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", b)
            Try
                radius = Integer.Parse(b)
                isGoodNumber = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                isGoodNumber = False
            End Try

            If Not isGoodNumber Then
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number.")
            End If

        Loop Until isGoodNumber

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

If you want to perform different actions depending on what error was thrown, you can use several `Catch` clauses:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim b As String
        Dim isGoodNumber As Boolean = True
        Dim radius As Integer

        ' OPTION TWO: Decline any bad input with a more specific error message.
        Do
            b = InputBox("Please enter the radius as a whole number:")
            Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", b)
            Try
                radius = Integer.Parse(b)
                isGoodNumber = True
            Catch ex As ArgumentNullException
                isGoodNumber = False
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number.")
            Catch ex As FormatException
                isGoodNumber = False
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number.")
            Catch ex As OverflowException
                isGoodNumber = False
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number between {0} and {1}", Integer.MinValue, Integer.MaxValue)
            End Try

        Loop Until isGoodNumber

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

In this case, if you don't need to give an bad-input-dependent error message, you don't even need the possibility of throwing an exception:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim b As String
        Dim isGoodNumber As Boolean = True
        Dim radius As Integer

        ' OPTION THREE: A shorter way of option one.
        Do
            b = InputBox("Please enter the radius as a whole number:")
            Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", b)
            isGoodNumber = Integer.TryParse(b, radius)
            If Not isGoodNumber Then
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number.")
            End If

        Loop Until isGoodNumber

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that the user may enter something other than an integer, so prepare for that. You almost did - but not in a great way. You thought of accounting for a non-integral number. But what about a non-numeric input, such as "abc"? For all cases, it's better to assume the user may enter a wrong input and use logic to check for it. You should use `If..Else` instead of `Try..Catch` to process that logic.

I also opted for using `Mod` since I couldn't figure out what `(b\0+1 = 1)` was supposed to do. The `\` rounds the number, discarding any remainder so that won't help you. Using `Decimal` data type to cover infinitesimally small remainders i.e. `1.0000000000000000000000000001` (but no less. See [MSDN Decimal Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx)). Note the `D` to coerce the operands of the `Mod` operator.

```
' I added declaration of 'b' here, assuming it's a string since InputBox returns string.
Dim b As String
b = InputBox("Please Enter Radius.")
Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", b)
Dim radius As Decimal
If Decimal.TryParse(b, radius) Then ' True if it's a number
    If radius Mod 1D = 0D Then ' True if it has no remainder
        Console.WriteLine("You entered an integral number. Good job")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Not a whole number. Please try again")
    End If
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Not even a number. Please try again")
End If
Console.ReadLine()
```